# I want to understand how this code can be implemented in the holoviews 1.12.7 version. I was done in depreciated version

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, holoviews

I want to understand how this code can be implemented using holoviews 1.12.7 version. I am using a depreciated version. Here is the sample code that I have run

```py
Chromosome = hv.Dimension('chromosome', unit='-', range=(AxesDF.loc['Min','Chr'],AxesDF.loc['Max','Chr']))
TraitIndex = hv.Dimension('trait index', unit='-', range=(AxesDF.loc['Min','Trait'],AxesDF.loc['Max','Trait']))
pP = hv.Dimension(r'$\mathsf{-log(p-value)}$', unit='-', range=(AxesDF.loc['Min','pP'],AxesDF.loc['Max','pP']))

SPlot_pP_Ch = holoviews.DFrame(GWASummaryStatisticsDF[['MHPos','pP-value']], dimensions={'MHPos':Chromosome,'pP-value':pP})

SPlot_Trait_Chr = holoviews.DFrame(GWASummaryStatisticsDF[['MHPos','TraitIndex','pP-value']],dimensions={'MHPos':Chromosome,'TraitIndex':TraitIndex,'pP-value':pP})

SPlot_Trait_Chr_pP = holoviews.DFrame(GWASummaryStatisticsDF[['MHPos','TraitIndex','pP-value']],dimensions={'MHPos':Chromosome,'TraitIndex':TraitIndex,'pP-value':pP})  

### Plots to Visualise: holoviews Scatter plots ##
### Example of Dataset in ***GWASummaryStatisticsDF dataframe*** ###
        MHPos   pP-value    TraitIndex
0   1.012324e+09    8.664141    1
1   1.738541e+09    7.485851    1
2   1.738436e+09    27.525929   1
3   1.738463e+09    56.837436   1
4   1.011689e+09    7.582362    1
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Can you add a text example of your data (not an image) and explain what kind of plot you would like to create? I would like to help you and that would make it a lot easier.

Comment: This is the kind of scatter plot that I would like to plot.

Comment: Hello Sander, This is the kind of scatter plot that I would like to plot. How can I share the sample data?. I am still k\new on Stackoverflow. Thanks

Comment: Here's an explanation of how people create and show data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

Okay, below is a small example of how to create a scatter plot with holoviews. If this is different from what you have or need, try to explain as clear as possible in your question what your data looks like and what you are looking for.

The `.DFrame()` method doesn't exist, so that's why you are getting your error message.

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

# create example data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'chromosome': np.random.rand(10),
    'trait_index': np.random.rand(10),
})

# create scatter plot
scatter_plot = hv.Scatter(
    data=df,
    kdims=['chromosome'],
    vdims=['trait_index'],
)

scatter_plot
```

Comment: Thanks let me try to implement and let you know.